# Flatten a pandas dataframe containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas, that contains lists at some entries

```
pandas = pd.DataFrame([[1,[2,3],[4,5]],[9,[2,3],[4,5]]],columns = ['A','B','C'])
```

I would like to know, how one can flatten this
dataframe to

```
pandas_flat = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[9,2,3,4,5]],columns = ['A','B_0','B_1','C_0','C_1'])
```

where the column names are adapted.

The next level is to flatten a pandas dataframe of lists with varying size in one column. How do I flatten them and fill in a `fill_value` as follows

```
pandas_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,[2,3,3],[4,5]],[9,[2,3],[4,5]]],columns = ['A','B','C'])
-->
fill_value = 0
pandas_flat_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,3,4,5],[9,2,3,0,4,5]],columns = ['A','B_0','B_1','B_2','C_1','C_2'])
```

--------------- Solution 
For the first dataframe

```
pandas = pd.DataFrame([[1,[2,3],[4,5]],[9,[2,3],[4,5]]],columns = ['Samples','B','C'])
```

we have

```
df=pandas.T.apply(lambda x: x.explode())
groups=df.groupby(level=0)
ids=groups.cumcount()
#df.index=(df.index+'_'+ids.astype(str)).mask(groups.size()<2,df.index.to_series())
new_df=df.T
# Change list names
m = list(new_df.columns)
d = {a:list(range(1, b+1)) if b>1 else '' for a,b in Counter(m).items()}
new_df.columns = [i+str(d[i].pop(0)) if len(d[i]) else i for i in m]
```

Comment: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(pandas_1.A.values.tolist()).add_prefix('A_'), pd.DataFrame(pandas_1.B.values.tolist()).add_prefix('B_'), pd.DataFrame(pandas_1.C.values.tolist()).add_prefix('C_')], axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you, can we stop the code from renaming the elements, that are not lists, i.e. that A is still A?

Comment: Does the list always have the same length?

Comment: Each column can have lists with the same length (case 1) or with differing lengths (case 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you could use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) + [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html). We can use to rename the columns [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df=pandas.T.apply(lambda x: x.explode())
ids=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df.index=df.index+'_'+ids.astype(str)
new_df=df.T
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  A_0 B_0 B_1 C_0 C_1
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   9   2   3   4   5
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
df=pandas.T.apply(lambda x: x.explode())
groups=df.groupby(level=0)
ids=groups.cumcount()
df.index=(df.index+'_'+ids.astype(str)).mask(groups.size()<2,df.index.to_series())
new_df=df.T
print(new_df)
  A  B_0 B_1 C_0 C_1
0  1   2   3   4   5
1  9   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but how can be stop this code from renaming A to A_0 if the column A does not contain lists.

Comment: Again, thank you. If I change the column names though, e.g. A to Samples, the error message reads "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" in the line df.index=(df.index+'_'+ids.astype(str)).mask(groups.size()<2,df.index.to_series())